# OpenERP incoming server configuration and Exchange server

Tags: odoo

My company uses Microsoft exchange mail server How could I configure incoming server with pop in OpenERP, which is hosted by sherweb2010 I know how to do for gmail and works fine, Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No There is not any Difference Between gmail and shareweb2010

if you configure the shareweb2010 then you can use the outlook setting in openerp